# Query Syntax for `Without Matching` keyword in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I found a very strange looking query in one of the MS-Access databases today:

```
SELECT Count([hrpersnl Without Matching T_Employees].EmpNo) AS [Count]
FROM [hrpersnl Without Matching T_Employees];
```

The `Without Matching` clause seems to me to be rather MS-Access specific syntax that differs from ANSI-SQL as a whole, it appears to me to be finding records that have no matches on the EmpNo field of both tables, but the `T_Employees` table does not have a `EmpNo` field, so I am probably wrong in my assumption about this.

What does it actually do, and where is the documentation for it?

Comment: Have you looked for saved queries that have those names? In your example everything within the square brackets should be the name of a Table or a Query.

Comment: Yes `hrpersnl` and `T_Employees` are both tables.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. Is there a saved query named `hrpersnl Without Matching T_Employees`?

Comment: I'm with Gord, there is no Ms Access syntax called `Without Matching`, surely that is the full name of a table/query? Perhaps a hidden table?

Comment: @MattDonnan RE: hidden table/query? - Good point! I hadn't thought about that....

Comment: Okay I'll bet I read that wrong... :-p  That's why I don't like the spaces in the query names in Access.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an Access query, table/query and field names that

- contain spaces and "funny characters", or
- are Access [reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738)

must be enclosed in [square brackets]. In this case, `[hrpersnl Without Matching T_Employees]` was a table or query name, not an expression involving the base tables `hrpersnl` and `T-Employees`.

Comment: Upvote.  For good reason, it's considered bad practice to include spaces when naming a table, query, or other Access database object.  It creates complications and hazards for the functioning of the program.  It works against legibility (as in this case).  And finally, it's obstacle to any future migration to another DBMS.